# I am trying to move a div by mouse on drag in Typescript React. This solution is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, web

This is the Code. But the window is moving away from the mouse after the first click.
How can I improve this code to make it clean and work? Is there any way around using 3 useeffects?

```
import { BsCircle } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

type Coordinates = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

const Index = () => {
  const [Mouse, setMouse] = useState<Coordinates | undefined>(undefined);
  const [newPosition, setNewPosition] = useState<Coordinates | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [isMoving, setIsMoving] = useState(false);
  const [hasMoved, sethasMoved] = useState(false);
  const windowRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const stylewindowContainer = hasMoved
    ? {
        top: newPosition?.y,
        left: newPosition?.x,
        position: "fixed" as "fixed",
        width: '37.5%',
        transform: 'none'
      }
    : { color: "black" };

    const startMoving = useCallback((e: MouseEvent) => {
      const Target = e.target as HTMLDivElement;
      setIsMoving(true);
      sethasMoved(true);
      setMouse({
        x: e.clientX - Target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: e.clientY - Target.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      });
      if (Mouse) {
      setNewPosition({x: e.clientX - Mouse?.x, y: e.clientY - Mouse?.y})
    }}, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!windowRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    
    const window: HTMLDivElement = windowRef.current;
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", startMoving);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", startMoving);
    };
  }, [startMoving]);
  
  const Moving = useCallback((e: MouseEvent) => {
    if (Mouse) {
      if (isMoving) {
        
    setNewPosition({x: e.clientX - Mouse?.x, y: e.clientY - Mouse?.y})
  }}}, [Mouse, isMoving]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!windowRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    const window: HTMLDivElement = windowRef.current;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", Moving);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", Moving);
    };
  },[Moving]);

  const stopMoving = useCallback(() => {
    setIsMoving(false)
  },[])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!windowRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    const window: HTMLDivElement = windowRef.current;
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", stopMoving);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopMoving);
    };
  },[stopMoving]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="IndexFirstView">
        <div className="IndexFirstViewContainer">
          <div className="IndexHeading">
            <p>
              <span></span>
              <span>
                
              </span>
            </p>
            <p>
              <span></span>
              <span id="name">something</span>
              <span>,</span>
            </p>
            <p id="jobTitle">Hello World!</p>
            <p id="jobTitle">Hello World!</p>
            <p id="jobTitle">Hello World!</p>
            <p id="jobTitle">Hello World!</p>
            <p id="jobTitle">Hello World!</p>
          </div>
          <div className="rightSide">
            <div
              style={stylewindowContainer}
              className="windowContainer"
              ref={windowRef}
            >
              <div className="topbar">
                <div className="windowBtns">
                  <span id="windowBtn">
                    <BsCircle />
                  </span>
                  <span id="windowBtn">
                    <BsCircle />
                  </span>
                  <span id="windowBtn">
                    <BsCircle />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="windowBottomContainer">
                <p>Hello World!</p>
                <p>
                  <br />
                </p>
                <p>
                  {newPosition?.x} : {newPosition?.y}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="IndexSecondView">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

My initial logic was to get the position of mousedown inside the window to get the relative position of the point where we can hold the window. store those coordinates in the Mouse and then update the position of the box with respect to the mousemove event coordinates subtracting the intitial Mouse Coordintes. It doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I find this https://dev.to/roggc/how-to-continuously-drag-an-element-in-react-with-javascript-4fon but is in JS, for TypeScript use this.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Ball=
()=>
{
  let offsetX:number;
  let offsetY:number;

  const move=(e:MouseEvent)=>
  {
    const el=e.target as HTMLDivElement
    el.style.left = `${e.pageX-offsetX}px`
    el.style.top = `${e.pageY-offsetY}px`
  }
  const add=(e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>):void =>
  {
    e.preventDefault()
    const el=e.target as HTMLDivElement
    offsetX=e.clientX - el.getBoundingClientRect().left
    offsetY=e.clientY- el.getBoundingClientRect().top

    el.addEventListener('mousemove',move)
  }

  const remove=(e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>):void=>{
    const el=e.target as HTMLDivElement
    el.removeEventListener('mousemove',move)
  }
  const Wrapper=styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 29px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
  cursor:pointer;
  z-indez:99;
  `
  return (
    <Wrapper onMouseDown={ add }  onMouseUp={remove}/>
  )
}
```